# How and when do I use useReducer in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Given the following component hierarchy:

```
Home (a page that consists of a list of names and a map with markers)
- PeopleList (the list of names)
  - PersonNameCard (the details for a single name)
- PeopleMap (a google map with markers for each person's location)
  - PersonPin (a map marker showing where someone is)
```

When I click a PersonPin (or the PersonNameCard), I want two things to happen:

1. to toggle the details of PersonNameCard (visible / collapsed)
2. to toggle the color of the pin (green to red, for example)

If I "[lift](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)" everything into the home and manage state via props and useState, I send a list of expanded PersonNameCards up and down the tree (down via props and up via state). As a side effect (because the expandedPersonNameCards prop changes), PeopleMap is re-rendered, which is undesirable.

When the map re-renders, its center and zoom return to their defaults. Thus, clicking a pin toggles the pin color, the PersonNameCard, and potentially pans and zooms the map back to its defaults (which is not desirable - I don't want the map to move when a pin is clicked).

It is my understanding that I may be able to use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to manage state between the grandchildren (who are cousins), but I can't figure out how. The documentation is just too sparse for my newbie brain. Thus, I have two questions:

1. Is this the use case that useReducer was designed for?
2. Where do I define the reducer and how do I call it?

I'm already concerned that by using useReducer I am [coupling components too tightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498075/how-to-avoid-coupling-when-using-usereducer) so any thoughts on that would be welcome as well.

Also, if useReducer is not the right way to go about this, what is?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question (but less concrete): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662592/usereducer-react-approach

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148972/best-way-to-setup-a-react-usereducer